# Angular component button not clickable

Tags: angular, button

I've an alert component in main page shown when an error occurred. This is my alert.html:

```
<div class="alert-body" *ngIf="error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" (click)="close(alert)">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
    <div class="alert-title">{{alert.title}}</div>
    {{alert.message}}
</div>
```

And this is my alert.ts:

```
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {
    error: boolean;
    ...
    close(alert) {
        console.log('close alert');
        // do stuff
        this.error = false;
    }
}
```

In css:

```
.close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    opacity: .2;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
}

button.close {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
```

In app.component I simply have:

```
...
<app-alert></app-alert>
...
```

The alert is correctly shown but the close button isn't clickable. Hover class isn't applied. It's like click event isn't catch. I tried with a z-index on button and span but nothing change.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Try getting rid of the span within the button tags. And then just have some text like "Close" between your button tags.

Comment: I just tried this on codesandbox and it works fine : https://codesandbox.io/embed/8nkpjo9xm2

Answer (score 0):

From what I can glean it looks like you've embedded this alert html into another page. Ideally alert should be its own component ([read this](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)). This would avoid the need to pass the 'alert' object to the close function and would probably resolve the issue of the button not being clickable. You can then use [selectors, inputs and emitters](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) as the basis of embedding a reference to this alert component in another component and passing inputs, outputs (if necessary).